# CRUD operation with Sugar CRM

Tags: sugarcrm

I have installed sugar CRM for my personal learning purpose, I want to create a module and simple CRUD operation with smarty, I went through documentation but I didn't get proper idea. I have tried to create a module with Hello World and it worked but I didn't get the proper MVC flow. Can we only create a module through module builder?
If someone know about this than please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: You can create a module from scratch, but it's not worth the effort. Create your module with Module Builder, set the fields, layouts, relationships, etc. Then Publish the module. You can open the resulting zip archive file to review how things work, and use it as a template in the future if you did want to create one from scratch.

Comment: What are you talking about? If you're asking about including files in SugarCRM we can talk about that, but your original question talks about creating a module. Can you edit your original question to be more clear? I don't understand what your end goal is.

Comment: thanks for your quick response . i created a module and it worked .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add,update and delete in SugarCRM using following actions.

**CRUD Handling:**

**Save Action:**

```
$bean = BeanFactory::newBean($module);   //Create bean
$bean->name = 'Example Record';   //Populate bean fields
$bean->save();   //Save
$record_id = $bean->id;  //Retrieve the bean id
```

---

**Update Action:**

```
$bean = BeanFactory::getBean($module, $id);      //Retrieve bean
$bean->update_date_modified = false;      //Set modified flag
$bean->name = 'Updated Name';  //Fields to update
$bean->save();   //Save
```

---

**Delete Action:**

```
$bean = BeanFactory::getBean($module, $id);     //Retrieve bean
$bean->deleted = 1;    //Set deleted to true
$bean->save(); //Save
```

Comment: can you give example of inserting data

Comment: i am able to update and delete but i am not able to insert how we need to pass module name ??